# Extract only city names in dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with location column

| A | location |
| --- | --- |
| a | Rehovot 2 |
| b | Tel Aviv,, |

I want to extract only city names and remove all unnecessary characters. So final output will be

| A | location |
| --- | --- |
| a | Rehovot |
| b | Tel Aviv |

I have tried this code so far:

```
df['location'] = df['location'].str.extract(r'[a-zA-Z]+\s?([a-zA-Z]+)?')
```

but its giving the error that pattern contains no matching group.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code removes any special characters from the column you want(while keeping white spaces) and the second line of code removes and numbers from the column you want

```
df['location'] = df['location'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','')
df['location'] = df['location'].str.replace('\d+', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in one line using **list comprehension** like :

```
df['location'] = [
    ''.join([el for el in city if el.isalpha() or el == ' ']) for city in df['location']
    ]
```

output:

```
   A  location
0  a  Rehovot 
1  b  Tel Aviv
```

The `.isalpha()` filters the string by keeping only alpha like characters (a, A, b, B...).